# Flag all invoices with a certain product in an Excel table

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data table, and I would like to "flag" all invoices that contain product "A", something like this:

[[image: Data Table]]

The same invoice can appear multiple times, associated with different products.  I need to flag the invoice rather than the product instance, so if an invoice meets the criterion, all instances of that invoice would get flagged.

I tried a couple of "IF"s but not getting what I want. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use COUNTIFS:

```
=--(COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,"A")>0)
```

Now if there is an `A` for that invoice then the COUNTIFS will return a number greater than `0` and the `--` will turn the TRUE into `1`

[image]

Comment: It worked! Also I didn't know the double dash (--) would turn True/False into 1/0. Thank you very much! :)